# Is this Traverse implementation for Functor and Option/Either correct?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, scala-3

I came across to this to functions, which implements `Traverse` for `Functor` and functions to `Option`/`Either` using new `boundary` capability:

```scala
def traverseToOption[F[_], A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => Option[B])(using functor: Functor[F]): Option[F[B]] =
  boundary:
    Some(functor.map(fa)(
      f(_) match
        case Some(value) => value
        case None => break(None)
    ))

def traverseToEither[F[_], A, B](fa: F[A])(f: A => Either[_, B])(using functor: Functor[F]): Either[_, F[B]] =
  boundary:
    Right(functor.map(fa)(
      f(_) match
        case Right(value) => value
        case Left(error) => break(Left(error))
    ))
```

I tested them like this:

```scala
case class Box[A](a: A)

given Functor[Box] with
  def map[A, B](fa: Box[A])(f: A => B): Box[B] = Box(f(fa.a))

traverseToOption(Box("123"))(_.toIntOption)                  // Some(Box(123))
traverseToEither(Box("123"))(_.toIntOption.toRight("Error")) // Right(Box(123))

traverseToOption(Box("abc"))(_.toIntOption)                  // None
traverseToEither(Box("abc"))(_.toIntOption.toRight("Error")) // Left(Error)
```

And results are correct. So, is this implementation generally correct? Can it be generalized to types other than `Option` and `Either`?

Comment: It could yes, but needs something more powerful than just a glorified exception. It needs full CPS transformation capabilities. That is basically what the whole **caprese** project aims to do, there are also some experimental compiler plugins already doing something similar, and you could check **unison** which is way more mature in this direction.